# Wordpress HOOK при активации плагина

Tags: wordpress, hook

Всем привет. Есть ли какой то хук который при активации плагина выполнит мой код?
Допустим я активирую Membership 2. При активации этого плагина я должен записать ему демо настройки. Но как мне зацепить именно этот плагин не изменяя его код?
Если кто-то знает, помогите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такой хук есть, но ничего не получится. Потому что хук `register_activation_hook()` должен вызываться до срабатывания `plugins_loaded` и обычно вызывается из основного файла плагина. См. [порядок срабатывания событий](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) WP при загрузке.

Куда вы поместите этот хук? Тема активируется позже всех плагинов, туда бесполезно. Можно попробовать написать свой плагин, который ставит хук на активацию Membership 2, но выглядит это достаточно криво.

Я бы посоветовал изучить код Membership 2 и решить задачу иным способом. Возможно, плагин оставляет какие-то отметки в базе при первой активации.